# phpmailer send gmail smtp timeout

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having trouble with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344239/having-trouble-with-phpmailer)

There are lots of similar questions , but none of them helped me.

Here's my script which is provided in the phpmailer exmaples:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
  $mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML("some message");
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

and here's the error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

in many questions it was mentioned to enable `php_openssl extenstion` which is enabled in my server. I'm using PHPmailer version 5.1

also there's no problem with my server port 25 and simple `mail()` function works fine

Thanks for your help

Comment: ping the host\port from the same server, in case its a network issue

Comment: @Dagon: pinging with no problem . I've also tried at localhost, and there's the same issue. I sent many emails using this approach several months ago and it was working fine , but now I've forgotten how to...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
  require_once ( 'class.phpmailer.php' ); // Add the path as appropriate
  $Mail = new PHPMailer();
  $Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
  $Mail->Host        = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server
  $Mail->SMTPDebug   = 2; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
  $Mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
  $Mail->SMTPSecure  = "tls"; //Secure conection
  $Mail->Port        = 587; // set the SMTP port
  $Mail->Username    = 'MyGmail@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username
  $Mail->Password    = 'MyGmailPassword'; // SMTP account password
  $Mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
  $Mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
  $Mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
  $Mail->Subject     = 'Test Email Using Gmail';
  $Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
  $Mail->From        = 'MyGmail@gmail.com';
  $Mail->FromName    = 'GMail Test';
  $Mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line

  $Mail->AddAddress( $ToEmail ); // To:
  $Mail->isHTML( TRUE );
  $Mail->Body    = $MessageHTML;
  $Mail->AltBody = $MessageTEXT;
  $Mail->Send();
  $Mail->SmtpClose();

  if ( $Mail->IsError() ) { 
    echo "ERROR<br /><br />";
  }
  else {
    echo "OK<br /><br />";
  }
```

Comment: works fine! thanks! but is there a same solution to send mail using yahoo accounts?

Comment: Just modify the SMTP parameters. I don't know them, but you can find them in Yahoo.