# PHP Mailer - SMTP GMAIL AUTHENTICATION

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I have problem with the PHP MAILER function. I am using GMAIL SMTP Authentication for sending email and also its working perfectly but i want to set "From" email like "myid@domainname.com" but it doesn't working properly.

I used below code to set "From" email

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "test@123";  

$mail->SetFrom("myid@domainname.com","Domian");
```

It's showing me default email test@gmail.com instead of myid@domainname.com

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail re-writes the headers on messages sent through smtp.gmail.com, replacing the FROM address with the gmail address associated with the gmail account that you are using to send the message through.  For more info, and a possible workaround, see: http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server

Answer (score 1):

It would go into the

```
$mail->From = "from@example.com"; 
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
```

Comment: If my answer helped or did not just let me know or mark as answer!

Comment: Getting same problem. I have used this code for setting custom header . $mail->AddCustomHeader('From:vijay.php@pnkinfocom.com');

Comment: Try $mail->From = "from@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";

Comment: Why do you set the host twice? also check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574166/phpmailer-send-gmail-smtp-timeout?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Gmail Settings -> Account -> Send email as -> Add another email address you own.
Add myid@domainname.com to your gmail account.

http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/52022f0a585d18-04883433

Gmail will hold a confirmation process account (will send an email with the code, etc.)

I'm not sure it would work. Try it.