# fsockopen error after upgrading to php 7

Tags: php, nginx, codeigniter-3

I run codeigniter3.03 on digital ocean nginx and  php 7. When I try to send an email I get this error:

Code:

> Severity: Warning
>   Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
>   Filename: libraries/Email.php
>   Line Number: 1986

My email setup is

```
$config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
//$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars'] = 76;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$config['priority'] = 3;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
```

This version runs flawlessly in the same config under php 5.x.

in php.ini i have

```
 extension=php_openssl.dll
```

enabled.

I could not get any hint anywhere why this should not work in php7. Can anybody give me a hint what to check or what the cause of this error could be.

Comment: "timed out". something prevent a network connection from being established. firewall or other network-level thing, maybe.

Comment: What exact version of PHP 5 do you use?

Comment: Also, looks like you're on Windows. Have you read a note here — http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an SSL or a PHP version issue. Have you tried doing a socket call like this `<?php fsockopen('smtp.googlemail.com', 465);` and see if this is getting timed out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `smtp.googlemail.com` already?

Also note this other answer, with a working example (seems to be different, for instance in the timeout definition):

- [phpmailer send gmail smtp timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574166/phpmailer-send-gmail-smtp-timeout)

Another solution:

- [Having trouble with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344239/having-trouble-with-phpmailer)