# php mailer not working. Mail error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

i cant send email using the php mailer class. here is the error i am getting.

### Error

> Mailer Error: The following From address failed: admin@mobilebitzltd.com : Called Mail() without being connected.

here is the code i am using.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com'; // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'admin@mydoamin.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'sdf'; // SMTP password
$mail->SetFrom($from, $from);
$mail->AddReplyTo($from, $from);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$address = $to;
$mail->AddAddress($address, $customer_name);

if (!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "Message sent!";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: please change your email password immediately.

Comment: It's better to change the password to mailserver. The pass is now in history of all edit

Comment: you changed it on live.com, not just in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the whole mail process into a try / catch block to get more information about the error as a good place to start.  There could be more details in the exception which could help pinpoint the problem.

```
try {
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from);
    ...
    ...
    $mail->Send();
} catch ( phpmailerException $e ) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); 
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

I found anther question that may be of some help which may be worth looking over: [Having trouble with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344239/having-trouble-with-phpmailer)

Most of all, I think its important someone point out you just posted your plain text password on the internet.  You may want to change it as quickly as possible **everywhere** it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
```

to get more information on what went wrong.

And try

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

at the top.

Comment: Hints from here may help your problem. [PHPMailer tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#External_SMTP_Servers_PHP_Mail)