# unable to send/receive email using php

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send email from my localhost website to gmail. I've changed the settings in php.ini and sendmail.ini I also enabled "less secured apps" in gmail but I cant' seem to send email to my gmail. Any help is appreciated! 
here is my code.

```
<?php      
$email_to = "myemail@domain.com";     
$email_subject = "testing";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
   !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
   !isset($_POST['email']) ||
   !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
   !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
           'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php      
die();
?>
```

Comment: Why oh why, are you using `@` ? It suppresses your errors and makes debugging impossible, remove it and try again.

Comment: @Epodax hello, i've removed `@` but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The function `mail()` will not work on your localhost, as the locahost doesn't works as a SMTP server, upload your content to a valid server with SMTP installed, and then go for the mail call.

There are some options for you listed below

1) To send mail from local server you have to configure SMTP on your server. You can use the googles free SMTP server Pretty easy to setup too.

2) Use **[php mailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)**

2) Use some 3rd party to send email like **[mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/)**.

Comment: Does it work if I have put SMTP server = smtp.gmail.com in my sendmail.ini folder?

Comment: Please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982821/send-email-from-localhost-with-gmailwindows)

Comment: thank you! and sorry if it's a duplicate I wasn't able to find that post just now