# send email from a localhost(XAMPP) using gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

> i have changed php.ini and sendmail.ini  to these settings: smtp.gmail.com (TLS enabled, port 587) and then i put auth_username and auth_password.

```
<?php
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "subject";
$txt = "How are you ?";
$headers = "From: example@example.com" . "\r\n";
$send=mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
if($send){
echo "sent";
}else{
echo "not sent";
}
?>
```

> i have tried send email using hotmail with changing the above settings and it worked, but with gmail not working...

Comment: Have you checked the spam-folder in gmail?

Comment: i did, actually  the code output not send from IF statement, but with hotmail it send

Comment: Have you also enabled php_openssl in your php.ini?

Comment: im not sure, can you describe more please?

Comment: Search for ;extension=php_openssl.dll in your php.ini and remove the semicolon.

Comment: maybe following link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982821/send-email-from-localhost-with-gmailwindows